# Undefined Reference to a template Const & function

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-reference

Function header:(Templated Outer Class Map has inner class Iterator)

```
Iterator insert(const std::pair<const T1, T2>&);
```

Function Implementation:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
typename Map<T1,T2>::Iterator insert(const std::pair<const T1, T2> &p)
```

Code to call insert function:

```
std::pair<int,char>p = std::make_pair(5, 'z');
mymap3.insert(p);
```

Compilation with g++ -g -std=c++11, Error:

```
 In function `main':
testmap.cpp:535: undefined reference to 
Map<int, char>::insert(std::pair<int const, char> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does the compiler assumer the definition of insert is now (pair const &) instead of my definition of (const pair &) is there a difference? Am I calling this inappropriately? I'm very befuddled. Yes, this is for class, we are re-implementing map. So the function definition was a given, I just need to find out how to call it and make it work.

Comment: `const T&` and `T const&` are the same. Are you defining the function in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: All of this code is within the same .cpp

Comment: And do you include the `.cpp` wherever it is needed? Actually, just post a simple test case from which the problem can easily be reproduced. If the code really is in the same `.cpp` you wouldn't be getting a linker error.

Comment: The main tester is within the same file of .cpp. Everything here is the same file. Class definition, implementations and testing.

Comment: So the `.cpp` file is what you refer to as the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
typename Map<T1,T2>::Iterator insert(const std::pair<const T1, T2> &p)
```

when declared outside the class definition of `Map`, is not a member function - it defines a global `insert`.

This is a member of `Map<T1, T2>` declared at namespace scope (i.e., outside the class definition):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
typename Map<T1,T2>::Iterator Map<T1,T2>::insert(const std::pair<const T1, T2> &p)
```

Note that the member function name has been qualified by the class name, which in this case is `Map<T1, T2>`.

On a related note, using a trailing return type would let you get rid of some of the nastiness in the return type, since names in a trailing return type are resolved in the scope of the class:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto Map<T1, T2>::insert(const std::pair<const T1, T2> &p) -> Iterator;
```

Comment: Yes this was the answer. Makes sense now. I got lost amidst all the c++ syntax. Although, I've never heard of a trailing return type in c++, I'll have to check that out.

Comment: @user1449870 the era of trailing return type will be short, as C++14 introduces return-type deduction and a simple `auto` will suffice in many cases.